# Pergunte ao usuário qual elemento ele quer remover do Array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Estou tentando criar um programa no qual um elemento possa ser adicionado ou removido do Array, de acordo com o que o usuário coloque no comando *prompt*. Estou tendo dificuldades em remover elementos do Array. Segue o meu programa:

```
    var regiaoAmazonica = ["Boca da Amazonia", "Vulcao", " Iracema", " Renato", "Macaco", " Santo Rafael", " Monte Mismi", " Mamiraua", " Tefe", " Alter Do Chao", " Manaus", " Rurrenabaque", " Rio Tabajós"];
    var nomeDoGuia = [" João Figueiredo", " Emílio Médici", " Luiz Inácio Lula da Silva", " Dilma Rousseff", " Michel Temer", " Alejandro Toledo", " Alan García Pérez", " Pedro Pablo Kuczynski", " Maria Sanchez", " Ranieri Mazzilli", " Martín Vizcarra", " Elías Rodríguez", " Margaret Thatcher"];
    var visitante = [" 4 estrelas", " 2 estrelas", " 2 estrelas", " 4 estrelas", " 0 estrelas", " 4 estrelas", " 2 estrelas", " 3 estrelas", " 0 estrelas", " 1 estrelas", " 3 estrelas", " 4 estrelas", " 2 estrelas"];
```

Adicionar nova regiões. Esse código não precisa de correção:

```
    var novaRegiaoAmazonica = prompt("Adicione uma nova regiao");
    var novoNomeDoGuia = prompt("Entre o nome de um novo guia");
    var novoVisitante = prompt("Entre sua nota para a regiao e o guia");

    regiaoAmazonica.push(novaRegiaoAmazonica);
    nomeDoGuia.push(novoNomeDoGuia);
    visitante.push(novoVisitante);

    var i = 0;
    while(i < regiaoAmazonica.length){
    document.write(regiaoAmazonica[i] + ", " + nomeDoGuia[i] + ", " + visitante[i] + '<br />');i++;
    }
```

Este é o codigo que não está funcionando. O usuário pode digitar o nome da região que quer deletar (e consequentemente as outras informações relacionadas à região). Caso o nome da região não exista, o usuário deve receber uma mensagem de erro.

```
    var deleteRegiaoAmazonica = prompt("Aqui esta a lista de regioes " + '\n' + amazonRegion + "Por favor digite a regiao que voce precisa remover da lista")

    var deleteRegiaoAmazonica = function() {
    var index = regiaoAmazonica.indexOf(deleteRegiaoAmazonica);
    if (deleteRegiaoAmazonica === RegiaoAmazonica[i] && index>-1) {
    RegiaoAmazonica.splice(index, 1);
    nomeDoGuia.splice(index, 1);
    visitante.splice(index, 1);
    document.write(RegiaoAmazonica);
    } else {
    alert("Erro");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Seu código possui vários erros. Você está chamando a variável `regiaoAmazonica` errada em 3 lugares, não respeitando o *case sensitive* inerente ao JavaScript. Também não precisa desse `function()`, já que seu código é executado de forma estruturada (linha por linha):

Eis o código corrigido:

```
var deleteRegiaoAmazonica = prompt("Aqui esta a lista de regioes " + '\n' + regiaoAmazonica + "Por favor digite a regiao que voce precisa remover da lista") // aqui estava em inglês

for(i=0,index=-1;i < regiaoAmazonica.length;i++){
    if(regiaoAmazonica[i].trim() == deleteRegiaoAmazonica || regiaoAmazonica[i] == deleteRegiaoAmazonica){
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

if (index > -1) {
    regiaoAmazonica.splice(index, 1); // aqui o primeiro "r" estava maiúsculo
    nomeDoGuia.splice(index, 1);
    visitante.splice(index, 1);
    document.write(regiaoAmazonica);  // aqui o primeiro "r" estava maiúsculo
} else {
    alert("Erro");
}
```

```js
var regiaoAmazonica = ["Boca da Amazonia", "Vulcao", " Iracema", " Renato", "Macaco", " Santo Rafael", " Monte Mismi", " Mamiraua", " Tefe", " Alter Do Chao", " Manaus", " Rurrenabaque", " Rio Tabajós"];
var nomeDoGuia = [" João Figueiredo", " Emílio Médici", " Luiz Inácio Lula da Silva", " Dilma Rousseff", " Michel Temer", " Alejandro Toledo", " Alan García Pérez", " Pedro Pablo Kuczynski", " Maria Sanchez", " Ranieri Mazzilli", " Martín Vizcarra", " Elías Rodríguez", " Margaret Thatcher"];
var visitante = [" 4 estrelas", " 2 estrelas", " 2 estrelas", " 4 estrelas", " 0 estrelas", " 4 estrelas", " 2 estrelas", " 3 estrelas", " 0 estrelas", " 1 estrelas", " 3 estrelas", " 4 estrelas", " 2 estrelas"];

var novaRegiaoAmazonica = prompt("Adicione uma nova regiao");
    var novoNomeDoGuia = prompt("Entre o nome de um novo guia");
    var novoVisitante = prompt("Entre sua nota para a regiao e o guia");

    regiaoAmazonica.push(novaRegiaoAmazonica);
    nomeDoGuia.push(novoNomeDoGuia);
    visitante.push(novoVisitante);

    var i = 0;
    while(i < regiaoAmazonica.length){
    document.write(regiaoAmazonica[i] + ", " + nomeDoGuia[i] + ", " + visitante[i] + '<br />');
 i++;
    }
 
 var deleteRegiaoAmazonica = prompt("Aqui esta a lista de regioes " + '\n' + regiaoAmazonica + "Por favor digite a regiao que voce precisa remover da lista")

    for(i=0,index=-1;i < regiaoAmazonica.length;i++){
  if(regiaoAmazonica[i].trim() == deleteRegiaoAmazonica || regiaoAmazonica[i] == deleteRegiaoAmazonica){
   index = i;
   break;
  }
    }

    if (index > -1) {
     regiaoAmazonica.splice(index, 1);
     nomeDoGuia.splice(index, 1);
     visitante.splice(index, 1);
     document.write(regiaoAmazonica);
    } else {
     alert("Erro");
    }
```

Comment: Uma observação, no *Array* dele tem alguns índices que começam com um *espaço*:  `"Boca da Amazonia", "Vulcao", " Iracema", " Renato"`, o que pode acontecer é o retorno do erro, porque não foi informado o espaço no *Prompt*.

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza Código atualizado para prever o espaço.

Comment: Muito obrigada!